Waking Screen After User Inactivity
In Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome, how can I 'wake up' the screen programmatically once it is has blanked due to user inactivity?
I tried the following:
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.ScreenSaver --object-path /org/gnome/ScreenSaver --method org.gnome.ScreenSaver.SimulateUserActivity

But received an error indicating that SimulateUserActivity is an unknown method (verified using 'gdbus introspect')
I then tried:
dbus-send --system --type=signal /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.WakeUpScreen

Unsurprisingly, that also did not work (no error, but screen stayed blank)
Finally, I tried using xdotool to simulate keypresses and mouse moves. Screen still stayed blank.

Why let it blank at all ?
